# Javascript - Redux actions don't run consecutively

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, queue, action

I have a situation when I need 2 Redux Actions to be run consecutively.
The context is a user clicks on a Preview button, and I want to display a loader until the puzzle is done generating.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onPreview: () => {
      dispatch(generatePreview());
    },
  };
}
```

In order to do it, I use the middleware [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and the action I want to be executed first returns a `Promise.resolve()` and my second action is in the `then()`:

```
export function generatingPreview() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: GENERATING_PREVIEW,
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
  };
}

export function generatePreview() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(generatingPreview()).then(() => {
      const state = getState();
      const conf = state.getIn(['login', 'conf']).toJS();
      const wordList = state.getIn(['login', 'wordList']);
      try {
        const newPuzzle = Wordfind.newPuzzleLax(wordList, conf);
        dispatch(generatePreviewSuccess(newPuzzle));
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch(generatePreviewError(err.message));
      }
    });
  };
}

export function generatePreviewError(error) {
  return {
    type: GENERATE_PREVIEW_ERROR,
    error,
  };
}

export function generatePreviewSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: GENERATE_PREVIEW_SUCCESS,
    payload,
  };
}
```

Unfortunately, the loader never appears. I console.logged the state setting the loading to true when my component renders, and it changes! I can see the log but not the loader, the component doesn't really re-render until the actions `generatePreviewSuccess()` or `generatePreviewError()` are dispatched. And it's not an issue from the loader, if I replace the `newPuzzleLax` function by a loop in order to make enough time to see it, I can see it!

My theory is this function `Wordfind.newPuzzleLax(wordList, conf)` that I use to generate the puzzle is blocking the queue of actions because on the Chrome Redux Tools I an see the first action appearing at the same time that the second one:
[Link to the function](https://github.com/bunkat/wordfind/blob/master/wordfind.js).

[image]

If I add a 1-microsecond delay between the dispatch of the two actions, the loader appears... but I would really like to understand what is happening. Thank you in advance. If it's any help, I use the [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

I also tried to transform the function generating the puzzle as an async one by doing this:

```
const wordFindAsync = async (wordList, conf) =>
  Wordfind.newPuzzleLax(wordList, conf);

export function generatePreview() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(generatingPreview())
      .then(() => {
        const state = getState();
        const conf = state.getIn(['login', 'conf']).toJS();
        const wordList = state.getIn(['login', 'wordList']);
        wordFindAsync(wordList, conf);
      })
      .then(res => dispatch(generatePreviewSuccess(res)))
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(generatePreviewError(err.message));
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't try to use `then()`? I've not ever had an issue doing something like `dispatch(isLoading(true)); dispatch(fetchResults()); dispatch(isLoading(false))`

Comment: `dispatch` runs synchronously, so you don't have to return `Promise.resolve()`, but rather just dispatch the actions in order.

Comment: @MarkC. @Yakimych I was doing it before. It actually works with another action when I call a Web Service (to print the puzzle) but not with this one... That's why I try to use `redux-thunk` and I think it comes from this function

Comment: You can still `dispatch` "normal" actions the old way even if you're using redux-thunk for asynchronous flow. The fact that the loading flag is set on the state confirms that the actions are dispatched correctly. Could it be that your component isn't subscribed to the relevant chunk of state and therefore doesn't get rerendered? Or that the "loading" happens fast and it gets hidden too quickly?

Comment: If the Loading indicator isn't shown, does that mean the puzzle is shown and drawn? Or is it not drawn yet?

Comment: About the loading happening too fast, it's not the case, I tried to replace the `newPuzzleLax()` function by a pretty long loop to see if it appears, and it's the case. If the Loading indicator isn't shown, that means the puzzle is not drawn yet, `generatePreviewSuccess` and `generatePreviewError` set the loading state to false.

Comment: @Yakimych how can I assure that the component is subscribed to the relevant chunk of state? As I said, when it changes I can see that `state.loading` is set to true by logging it when the component `render()`, but it doesn't actually re-render until the `newPuzzleLax()`  is done trying to generate the puzzle.

Comment: If you're using `react`, the typical way would be to either connect your component to the store via react-redux [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), or make sure the parent is connected and rerenders the children with fresh props. I've looked at your GitHub link, but can't find any traces of redux, so it's hard to know how you're using it - would be helpful to see the relevant code.

Comment: so your saying you wanna display a loader until the puzzle is done generating...does that mean `Wordfind.newPuzzleLax` is an async function? If so how come you're not using a callback?

Answer (score 0):

In your second version you're not returning the Promise from `wordFindAsync(wordList, conf)` back into your original Promise chain, and so its not being resolved/waited on by then next `then`.

```
export function generatePreview() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(generatingPreview())
      .then(() => {
        const state = getState();
        const conf = state.getIn(['login', 'conf']).toJS();
        const wordList = state.getIn(['login', 'wordList']);
        return wordFindAsync(wordList, conf); //  return your promise here 
      })
      .then(res => dispatch(generatePreviewSuccess(res)))
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(generatePreviewError(err.message));
      });
  };
}
```

---

Here's a simple example demoing the behavior I'm refering to.

This one will only wait 1 second until logging "done":

```js
const waitOneSec = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("waiting 1 secoond");
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });

waitOneSec()
  .then(() => {
    waitOneSec(); // Promise not returned
  })
  .then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Whereas this one will wait full 2 seconds until logging "done":

```js
const waitOneSec = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("waiting 1 secoond");
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });

waitOneSec()
  .then(() => {
    return waitOneSec(); //  Promise returned
  })
  .then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, even with your solution I still encounter a strange issue: my UI doesn't re-render even if on the Chrome Inspector it does: https://www.useloom.com/share/030fed4ff09145e49a64e4e614709310 In order to be sure to see if my Container was seeing the state getting updated I put this on top of my `render()` function: `if (this.props.puzzleLoading === 'true') { return <h1>Loading</h1>; }` and as you can see in the video, it works! But only the code, not the UI...